# How to compare two array objects and populate data in first array in vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have two array objects `defaultPermissions and userPermissions`. `defaultPermissions` contains all the permission with default value as 0 for `read, write, update, delete`. `userPermissions` contains data for which the users has been given permission for.

I have a table with permission name and checkbox for each operation. If the users has been given a permission for `read, write, update, delete` of the respective `PemissionName` then the checkbox should be `checked` else it should be `unchecked`.

I have done by hardcoding the `userPermissions` and it is working, but my problem is if in future a new `PermisssionName` is added then I will have to hard code it again which is not the correct way.

Whenever any new `PermisisonName` is added it should dynamically be shown as `checked` or `unchecked` for each user.

Any suggestion on how this can be done - Thank You.

First array:

```
defaultPermissions : [
    {'permission_name':'PermissionName1', 'read':0, 'write':0, 'update':0, 'delete':0},
    {'permission_name':'PermissionName2', 'read':0, 'write':0, 'update':0, 'delete':0},
    {'permission_name':'PermissionName3', 'read':0, 'write':0, 'update':0, 'delete':0},
    {'permission_name':'PermissionName4', 'read':0, 'write':0, 'update':0, 'delete':0},
    {'permission_name':'PermissionName5', 'read':0, 'write':0, 'update':0, 'delete':0},
    {'permission_name':'PermissionName6', 'read':0, 'write':0, 'update':0, 'delete':0},
    {'permission_name':'PermissionName7', 'read':0, 'write':0, 'update':0, 'delete':0},
    {'permission_name':'PermissionName8', 'read':0, 'write':0, 'update':0, 'delete':0},
    {'permission_name':'PermissionName9', 'read':0, 'write':0, 'update':0, 'delete':0},
    {'permission_name':'PermissionName10', 'read':0, 'write':0, 'update':0, 'delete':0},

]
```

Second array:

```
userPermissions:[
    {'permission_name':'PermissionName1', 'read':1, 'write':1, 'update':1, 'delete':1},
    {'permission_name':'PermissionName2', 'read':1, 'write':1, 'update':1, 'delete':1},
    {'permission_name':'PermissionName3', 'read':1, 'write':1, 'update':1, 'delete':1},
    {'permission_name':'PermissionName4', 'read':1, 'write':1, 'update':0, 'delete':0},
    {'permission_name':'PermissionName5', 'read':1, 'write':1, 'update':0, 'delete':0},
    {'permission_name':'PermissionName6', 'read':0, 'write':0, 'update':0, 'delete':0},
    {'permission_name':'PermissionName7', 'read':0, 'write':0, 'update':0, 'delete':0},
    {'permission_name':'PermissionName8', 'read':0, 'write':0, 'update':0, 'delete':0},
    {'permission_name':'PermissionName9', 'read':1, 'write':1, 'update':1, 'delete':1},
    {'permission_name':'PermissionName11', 'read':1, 'write':1, 'update':1, 'delete':1},
]
```

Table row code for display all the `PermissionName` along with respective operations as `checked` or `unchecked`

```
<tr v-for="(item,index) in defaultPermissions" :key="index">
    <td> {{ item.resourceName }}</td>
    <td> <input type="checkbox" v-model=" item.read " class="form-control"/></td>
    <td> <input type="checkbox" v-model=" item.write " class="form-control"/></td>
    <td> <input type="checkbox" v-model=" item.update " class="form-control"/></td>
    <td> <input type="checkbox" v-model=" item.delete " class="form-control"/></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: So `userPermissions` array could have less objects than `defaultPermissions`, that's your problem, right?

Comment: yes, but the table which displays the permissions should contain all the objects of `defaultPermissions` and the operation checkbox must be checked if it is true in `userPermissions`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you have to get *merged* permission arrays, e.g. `defaultPermissions` with `userPermissions` over it:

```js
computed: {
  permissions() {
    const uperms = this.userPermissions
      .reduce((acc, u) => ({ ...acc, ...{ [u.permission_name]: u } }), {});
    return this.defaultPermissions
      .map((d) => ({ ...d, ...(uperms[d.permission_name] || {}) }));
  },
},
```

Next, you have to properly handle checkbox changes:

```html
<tr v-for="item in permissions" :key="item.permission_name">
  <td> {{ item.permission_name }}</td>
  <td v-for="perm in ['read', 'write', 'update', 'delete']"
      :key="`${item.permission_name}-${perm}`">
    <input type="checkbox" class="form-control"
           :checked="item[perm]"
           @change="setPerm(item.permission_name, perm, $event.target.checked)"/>
  </td>
</tr>
```

```js
methods: {
  setPerm(permission_name, perm, val) {
    const uperm = this.userPermissions
      .find((p) => p.permission_name === permission_name);
    if (uperm == null) {
      this.userPermissions.push({
        permission_name,
        read: 0, write: 0, update: 0, 'delete': 0,
        ...{ [perm]: val|0 },
      });
    } else {
      uperm[perm] = val|0;
    }
  },
},
```

That's all. Optionally, you'd want to remove empty permissions from `userPermissions` before saving them:

```js
const filteredPerms = this.userPermissions
  .filter((u) => (u.read || u.write || u.update || u.delete));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can map the `defaultPermissions`, and assign the values of user permission, whenever such a permission exists. When userPermission does not exists assign an empty object (only to get a one line solution):

```
defaultPermissions = defaultPermissions.map(perm => {
   return Object.assign(perm, userPermissions.find(u => u.permission_name === perm.permission_name) || {})
})
```